# Can't deploy simple node js react app to elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ok guys this should be simple and I watched all tutorials online via Youtube and Medium articles and they all have the same steps. I tried the CLI and uploading the source code but when i check the logs I get this error

An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error signal: killed. Stderr:npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.

I obviously tried doing npm install --omit dev and I still get the same error.

Here is [image: my project structure]

[image: here is my package json]

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a monorepo for both, your frontend (React) and your backend (Node.JS). You might want to think about splitting those and use a service that is a better fit for your frontend like [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/). You don't need an EC2 server that is running 24/7 for your frontend. Once your frontend app is built, it only requires static hosting. That's what Amplify is for and it comes with many other benefits like automated domain config, CDN, etc.

That said, even though it comes with a bunch of downsides, it is possible to run both frontend and backend in 1 repo using Beanstalk. To achieve this, you will need to launch the server side (Node.JS) and statically host your frontend (React) `/build` directory at the same time.

### npm start

Let's fix your `npm start` command. You only need the last part `node server.js`. Beanstalk will run `npm install && npm build` for you automatically as part of the deployment process.

If you have both frontend and backend in one repo, make sure to use separate `package.json` files in separate subdirectories. Avoid installing backend and frontend modules into the same `node_modules` directory.

Make sure to trigger the build process for both, frontend and backend when Beanstalk runs `npm run build`. You can play with the scripts in your main `package.json`. Here's an example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:frontend": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build",
    "build:backend": "cd backend && npm install && npm run build",
    "build": "npm run build:frontend && npm run build:backend",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Make sure to generate separate build outputs. E.g. `/dist` for your backend and `/build` for your frontend, or ideally, put them in subdirectories for better separation, e.g. `/frontend/build` and `/backend/build`.

You can even add a third overarching `package.json` to structure your directories. This third `package.json` will not have any dependencies, its only job is to manage your scripts for Beanstalk.

```
├── backend
│   ├── build <-- you won't have one if you're using plain js
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src <-- this will be started with `node /backend/src/server.js`
├── frontend
│   ├── build <-- content of this will be statically hosted
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
└── package.json
```

### Static hosting (nginx proxy)

The next step is to make sure the build output of your frontend is hosted statically. While you can achieve this with Express, e.g. by using `app.use(express.static('frontend/build'))`, there is a much better option that comes with Beanstalk: **nginx**

Beanstalk manages an nginx instance that can host static directories for you. Like most SPAs, React requires dynamic routing that redirects all requests to `index.html`. Nginx makes this configuration really easy. You can replace Beanstalk's default nginx config by putting a file in your app directory under `/.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Here's an example that will route all `/api` traffic to your Node.JS server (make sure it listens on the right port 3000). It will route all remaining traffic to a static directory `/var/app/current/frontend/dist` - this should be pointing to your frontend build files.

```
http {
    server {

        listen 8080;
        root /var/app/current/frontend/dist;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000/api;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
}
```

Like I said, you can also [use Express to host static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) but I would recommend the nginx approach since Beanstalk already comes with nginx and it makes the redirect config easier.